# Current Spike when charger plugged in?

Tags: relay, current-measurement, debugging, troubleshooting, spike

Here is the rough set up of the system:
[image]

Relays used 1-1393277-4 (https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2243264.pdf ).

The way the set up works is when the battery is turned on, there is a micro (not shown) which waits 30 seconds and then energises relay coils which turns them on, connecting the battery directly to the motor controllers.

The 30seconds are there to allow the battery to precharge the motor controllers which form a fairly big capacitive load (estimated around 5mF). It also means the switching voltage for the relay is significantly lower which should protect it from damage. I know we should be using hotswaps in stead of relays here but lets ignore that.
I have measured the voltage on the motor controller side and by the time the relay closes it is almost at the same voltage as the battery.

However, there have been two rare instances where Relay 1 has failed (its contacts basically have welded) and this creates in rush issues on the battery. The only information i have is in both cases the charger was connected.

I have tried to fail this relay myself but haven't been successful at recreating the issue. What i did notice however is if i plug in the charger and the relays have already been closed (there is a path to controllers) i see a 30A current spike from the motor controller side (as shown in the image). This can be seen below:
[image]

It also seems like that current spike is clipping in the end. But the strangest thing is how this current is measured on the motor controller cable. Surely no current should be flowing from there? If the caps on the charger need to charge initially this should happen from the battery which is the path of least resistance and not the motor controller side?

Comment: A good idea for a precharger is a voltage monitor, to gate the relay pulling in until the ESC is up to voltage. And preferably a timeout as well, to turn off the precharge resistor in case the ESC is faulty (failed short?) i.e. it never charges up.  As for the transient, perhaps the ESC was accidentally turned on, discharging its supply before the relay pulled in?

Comment: The only way to turn on the ESC is through the relay though so i can't see that happening? Yes a voltage monitor would be great. Basically a hotswap IC which does all of that for you. I just don't understand what caused the relay to weld.

Comment: What caused it to weld? A voltage drop, obviously. What caused the voltage drop? No idea. If it's any help, the information you have presented so far, does not offer any clues. If there is an answer, it seems elsewhere than you've been looking (assuming what you've presented so far, is everything that you know as yet).

Comment: But about that: how, exactly, does the ESC know it's being turned on, if the relay just bypasses the precharge resistor? So it's already at full voltage? What more can it know? Is there more to this than is shown?

Comment: @TimWilliams when the system turns on the MCU waits for 30 seconds and keeps the relay open allowing precharge resistor to charge up the ESC. By the time the relay closes the ESC is pretty mich (maybe 100mV off) from the voltage on the battery.

Comment: Ah. Then checking what the MCU is doing, perhaps logging erroneous conditions, might prove worthwhile. Software is ALWAYS the first suspect!

Comment: The ESC has a logic side (24V) which is turned on through the MCU and is protected via an efuse. The logic side would already been on before the power side with the relay turns on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138235/discussion-between-hasman404-and-tim-williams).